# MySQL DEFAULT vs. MariaDB DEFAULT

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have `table_a` with and `auto_increment` column named `id` and string column named `name`.

Running the statement:
`INSERT INTO table_a(id, name)VALUES(DEFAULT, 'test');`

Results to (MySQL):

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------|
| 1  | test |
+----+------+
```

Running the similar statement in `MariaDB` results to:

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------|
| 0  | test |
+----+------+
```

Other scenario:

I tried editing the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value of the table to 30. MySQL inserts 30 while MariaDB inserts 0.

What is the difference of `DEFAULT` value in `INSERT` statement of MySQL and MariaDB? Is this a bug in MariaDB or it is working as intended?

Comment: Can you add how the table is created in MariaDB? ( use `SHOW CREATE TABLE tableNameHere` ). It appears that the table in MariaDB doesn't have auto increment set.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE 'table_a' (
  'id' bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'name' varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('id')
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`

Comment: Then u should try this INSERT INTO table_a(name)VALUES( 'test');   Discard id while inserting

Comment: While it does work, I'm still trying to figure out what causes the statement to insert 0 in MariaDB.

Comment: Returns the default value for a table column. If the column has no default value, NULL is returned. For integer columns using AUTO_INCREMENT, 0 is returned.

Comment: Check this link for more details       https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/default/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is controlled by `SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'`, both in MySQL and MariaDB. If you observe the difference, it's most likely because you have different `sql_mode` on the instances.

```
MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE t (id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.20 sec)

MariaDB [test]> SET SQL_MODE='';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO t (id) VALUES (DEFAULT);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

MariaDB [test]> SELECT * FROM t;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> DROP TABLE t;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)

MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE t (id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.30 sec)

MariaDB [test]> SET SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO t (id) VALUES (DEFAULT);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [test]> SELECT * FROM t;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  0 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```